# How to set uniqueness for more than 2 columns using an sql query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table with 4 columns out of which one column needs to be in a set of data and other 3 needs to be unique in the entire table. Below is an example

Table Name : tblEmployee

```
EmployeeId  EmployeeName EmployeeType DateOfJoining ManagerId
     1       John           Dev         1 feb 2016     12
     2       Steve          Tester      1 feb 2015     8
     3       Bob            Admin       1 jan 2016     5
```

I need to check managerid is in a master table and EmployeeName, EmployeeType, DateOfJoining are unique in the entire table using a single sql query.I have tried Sub queries,Partitions and event functions but finding it difficult.

I'm using sql server 2008 now

Comment: Do you mean individually unique, or as a combination?

Comment: Put a unique key on those colums.

Comment: @jarlh no i wanted to check it in a combination

Comment: @lolka_bolka how do you add a unique key for 4 columns with one column that needs to be checked if it is present in a table or not

Comment: ALTER TABLE tblEmployee WITH NOCHECK 
ADD CONSTRAINT UNIQ_name UNIQUE (col1,col2,col3,col4)

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Col4 needs to be in a master and needs to have IsUniqueCol = 1 only then should we check for Col1,Col2 and Col3 to be unique

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question correctly you can use a unique index for the three columns:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_tblEmployee] ON [dbo].[tblEmployee] (
    [EmployeeName], 
    [EmployeeType], 
    [DateOfJoining]) 
    WITH (
          STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
          ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Then you can add a foreign key to check whether the `ManagerId` column contains a valid value from table `tblManager`:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.tblEmployee ADD CONSTRAINT
       FK_tblEmployee_tblManager FOREIGN KEY (ManagerId) 
       REFERENCES dbo.tblManager (ManagerId) 
       ON UPDATE  NO ACTION 
       ON DELETE  NO ACTION
```

Is that what you actually wanted?

Comment: so the problem is that only for specific managers only i needs to check this uniqueness,like i have a key called IsUnique in tblManager and only for managers who have IsUnique as 1 will be checked for above 3 columns

Comment: Then you'll have to use a function, there is no built-in support for this kind of dependencies. See Tab's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a [CHECK CONSTRAINT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258(v=sql.105).aspx) that calls a UDF.

Write a function that returns either 1 if the record meets all of your requirements, or 0 if not, then add a check constraint that checks if the result of your function is 1.